# How to pass LinkedHashMap from FragmentPagerAdapter to Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Below is example of passing an Int value using `args.putInt.` Similarly I want to pass `employee_map`. How to pass Map object as Bundle args to Fragments. I don't want to pass in as list.

**MyFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
@Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      LinkedHashMap<String,Employee> employee_map;
      Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
      fragment.setArguments(args);
      return fragment;
    }
```

**MyFragment extends Fragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       int fragmentNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyFragmentPageAdapter

```
 @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          LinkedHashMap<String,Employee> employee_map;
          Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
          args.putSerializable("employee_map", employee_map);
          fragment.setArguments(args);
          return fragment;
        }
```

MyFragment.java

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       int fragmentNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
       employee_map = (LinkedHashMap<String, Employee>) getArguments().getSerializable("employee_map");
}
```

> Important: `Employee` implements `java.io.Serializable`